# Perform a task at a specific time

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio. I have 0 Experience with Java and was still successful to send SMS using my app.

> How to Send that SMS at a specific time. E.g; at 5 o'clock.

I have tried `com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY`, etc but unable to get the permission to send SMS in my other task name `MyTask.java`

The code is used in mainactivity.java is

```
package com.example.ssss;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.PeriodicTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 1;
    String SENT = "SMS_SEND";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI, deliveredPI;
    BroadcastReceiver smsSentReceiver, smsDeliveredReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GcmNetworkManager networkManager=GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this);


        String s1 = "MY MSG";
        String TellNO = "THE NUMBER";
        sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);




        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
        else
        {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(TellNO, null, s1, sentPI, deliveredPI);
        }



    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `AlarmManagerCompat` for that

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alarmmanager to schedual a call to a method which fetch no. from your database and send your desired message to that number.

From android docs:

AlarmManager:This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered for it is broadcast by the system, automatically starting the target application if it is not already running.